# Noun order in a noun phrase

Tags: word-order

Is there any rule of where to place the name of a brand/movie/book (before or after the noun)?

I would usually put it before the noun if the name has only one word. Examples:

- The "Apple" brand is worth billions of dollars.
- The "Cambridge" dictionary is very good.

But I am not sure when the name has more than one word. Examples:

- The movie "The Untouchables" / "The Untouchables" movie is great!
- The website "Stack Exchange" / "Stack Exchange" website is popular.

Comment: There is no need for all those apostrophes.

Comment: Not even in the multi-word names?

Comment: No, never. In a publication, they sometimes put names of publications in italics.

Comment: The issue here is that usually, one would write: The Untouchables is a great movie. If you write, The Untouchables movie, it is usually to contrast it with The Untouchables book, for example.

Answer (score 4):

When the proper name (Apple inn this case) functions as an adjective (more strictly as a noun adjunct in amny cases), modifying the noun as in

> The Apple brand is worth billions of dollars

most often the name goes before the common noun. But when the generic term (the word that describes the kind of thing this is, "movie" in this case) serves as an adjective or noun adjunct, as in

> The movie *The Untouchables* was very good.

In short, whichever term is functioning as an adjective, to modify the other, which is functioning as the main noun of a noun phrase, tends to go first.

However, these are only tendencies, and contrary examples can be framed that will work.

(Quotes are used for titles of short works. Italics are used for full-length films, books, and other independent works. Quotes can also be used to indicate that a word is beign mentioned, not used as in *The word "three" has five letters.*)

Comment: You say "when the name functions as an adjective" and then "when the generic term serves as an adjective"? Name = generic term? I have not understood the difference between the both situations. Could you make it clearer?

Comment: @Alan I have edited the answer in an effort to make it more clear. Please read it and leave a comment telling me if that helped or not. I used "generic" as the opposite of "proper name" here.

Comment: It is clear now, thanks! However, I don't think that "movie" is an adjective in my example. "movie" cannot be anything else than a noun.

Comment: @Alan Within a Noun Phrase,consisting of several nouns  one noun, usually the last mentioned, severs as the primary or head noun, and other nouns are Noun Adjuncts and serve to modify the head noun, and therefore function as adjectives. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. IMHO the term "noun adjunct" (or "qualifier noun") is more accurate than "adjective" and avoids confusion. Anyway, the most important question is still open: how do I choose which noun qualifies and which one is qualified? (the movie XYZ vs the XYZ movie) ? For instance, why would I choose "movie" to be the qualifier noun of "The Untouchables" instead of the other way around?